# Sqlite3 .database command in python

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-views

I am trying to view all the databases in sqlite3. It can be done through the command line with .database command. I want to do the same thing in Django and show the render the details in HTML.

The following is the code I wrote in the views file:

```
def analyzer(request):
conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3") 
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
l = c.fetchall()
print (l)
return render(request, 'analyzer.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use [`PRAGMA database_list;`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list). That, like the .databases command, will show all the *attached* databases.

The tables for the main database can be retrieved with

```
SELECT name 
from sqlite_master
where type = 'table';
```

For attached dbs, prefix `sqlite_master` with the attached db's name and dot (eg `db2.sqlite_master`). You probably want to filter out tables that begin with `sqlite_`

Comment: It worked. Can you please also help me on how to get all table listed under particular databases?

Comment: Info added to answer.